# Flow Decision Element: Is it a Weekday?

Tags: salesforce

I've got a Flow that runs daily.  The 1st element is a Decision that evaluates whether it is a weekday (see images below).

My issue is that the Flow triggers on Saturdays but not Sundays, and I need help figuring out why.  I've included a screenshot that returns the day of the week (varDayOfWeek). Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf9wp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/58YRP.png

Expecting the Flow to not run on Saturdays or Sundays